# Reduce git subtree commit log noise

Tags: git, github, yeoman, git-subtree

I use Yeoman for deployment of my web app. As per the suggestion of [the Yeoman docs](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html), I deploy my site using `git subtree`, doing something like this:

1. `grunt build`
2. `git add -A dist`
3. `git commit -m "New release"`
4. `git subtree push --prefix dist origin deploy`

Then, on the staging server, the very first time I do:

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add -t deploy -f origin git@github.com:cdmckay/example.git`
3. `git checkout deploy`

Then, every time after that I do:

```
git pull
```

However, this causes a couple things I don't like.

Firstly, my `master` branch now has `dist` folder, which I think is ugly.

Secondly, my git history gets chocked full of `New release` messages, as every time I want to push the Yeoman app to my staging server, I have to make another commit.

Is there a better way to set up my deployment such that I can keep the `dist` folder out of the `master` branch and get rid of the deployment commit messages?

Answer (score 1):

Is the pull ever going to need to do a content merge, or will complete replacement be enough?

Complete replacement is, on `build`,

```
git tag -f dist `git commit-tree -m - master:dist`
git push -f origin dist
```

and on the staging server:

```
git checkout -f dist  # possibly with `-f`
```

---

git doesn't attach HEAD to tags and this tag is of no-history commits, so there's nothing to get out of sync, it's a raw content push with a throwaway tag name.

Comment: It'll always be a complete replacement... but I'm starting to think maybe using git for deployment isn't the best fit?

Comment: Yep.  You'll find a lot of replies on here "git isn't a deployment server", but it's fallen out of fashion because so many people want to use what's right in front of them and git's a unix tool: like many of them, you can bludgeon it into doing just about anything.  All the same, this does work.

Comment: edit: hang on, this isn't the question I thought, [I found a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23837283/1290731).