# How can I clone only a subfolder of a Git repository and make all the files in the subfolder end up in the root?

Tags: git

I realize that similar questions has been asked before: [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) However I couldnt find the answer to my specific question so please do not mark it as duplicate.

I have a subfolder called statics/ in my repo. I want the files of that subfolder end up in the root of my local repo.

I did `echo statics/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout` but I end of with `/statics/file.css` in my local repo when I do a pull. I just want `/file.css`.

How do I do this?

Reference of commands used:

```
git init
git remote add -f https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo statics/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `statics` once you've got its contents hoisted to the root?  Is just getting the content of an arbitrary version enough (that's easy), or do you need to develop in it independently but still collaborate with the main project, or what?  Describe the situation you're in and what needs doing without referring to features or abstractions of any vcs.

Comment: @jthill It just need to get content from an arbitrary version. It will NOT be developed independently. Do you have any idea how this can solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's `git checkout` for an arbitrary tree.  Have a branch you call `scratchpad` whose content you might occasionally want to record for posterity.

```
git checkout scratchpad
git read-tree -um --aggressive `git write-tree`: anycommityoulike:statics
```

and any time that balks at overwriting worktree content and you just don't care, change `-um` to `-u` and do a `git checkout -f` afterwards.

edit: just do the checkout while we're already there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible: sparse checkout mechanics is not a file relocation tool. As explained [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) when you employ sparse checkout, Git only operates on special bits set for entries in the index file.  It does not relocate anything.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is good enough if not someone else has another idea of how this can be solved.